Why is the following code going into an infinite loop
Consider the below code:
#include <iostream>
    
using namespace std;
    
class Buffer {
public:
    static const int BufferSize=5;
    Buffer() {
        for(this->index=0;this->index<=BufferSize;this->index+=1) {
            BufArr[this->index]=0;
            cout<<"index: "<<index<<"\n";
        }
    }
    int BufArr[BufferSize];
    int index;
};
    
int main() {
    Buffer b;
    return 0;
}

If we run this code, it prints:
0
1
2
3
4
0
1
2
3
4
...

and keep printing, why? It should stop (as we have index<=BufferSize condition).
Please help me understand this.

Just an off-topic note: you don't need this-> here at all: instead of this->index, it should be just index. Less clutter.

See Undefined Behaviour.

The condition of your loop is:
this->index<=BufferSize

Which means that in the last iteration index will be 5.
Then BufArr[this->index] is accessing the array out-of-bounds which causes UB (undefined behavior). It means the standard gives no guarantee about the behavior of the program.
You need to use < instead of <=:
this->index<BufferSize

Live demo
A side note:
See: What's the problem with "using namespace std;"?

Note:
As @AlanBirtles commented below although in principle when UB ensues anything can happen, in this simple case it is quite obvious why on most implementations the original code will produce an infinite loop:
index is of the same type as the elements in BufArr and is probably stored right after BufArr in the object, and so when writing 0 to BuffArr[5] it is essentially the same as assigning index to 0.

Why is it running infinite?(why index moves to 0 again after index=4 instead of 5 and gives error) It should give out-of-bound/overflow error?
It is not falling into the infinite loop when BufArr[this->index]=num(not 0) ? Why so?

As I mentioned, when undefined behavior ensues, there's no guarantee about the behavior. It could issue an error or do anything else. More info about it is here.

Though the behaviour is undefined it's fairly predictable what'll happen in most c++ implementations, index is stored right after BufArr so BuffArr[5] is essentially the same as index so BufArr[5]=0 resets index to 0

@AlanBirtles this makes sense of course, and I agree it is probably the reason in this simple case. I thought it is better to focus on the issue of UB and how to avoid it, but anyway added a comment with your insight.

@AlokRanjanSrivastava Your making the mistake of thinking that C++ checks for errors. In general it does not. It's up to you to get your code right, and if you don't the behaviour of your code is unpredictable (or strictly speaking it's undefined).

Arrays are 0 indexed. This means while you count 5 Values (1,2,3,4,5) Arrays count with: 0,1,2,3,4  your for-loop asks for smaller-equal to Buffersize (<=) while it should be <. Your array runs in the current state out of bounds which causes an overflow which again causes Undefined Behaviour
